# Как происходит перезаписывание конструктора в прототипе

Tags: javascript, prototype

Если создать новый объект с помощью Object.create и указать в нём прототип и сделать его прототипом конструктора, родной конструктор не перезапишется.
А если просто объект сделать прототипом конструктора, то он перезапишется.
Как это удаление происходит? Не понимаю логику перезаписи конструктора.
Или так поставлю вопрос. Почему в первом случае конструктор не перезаписался, а во втором перезаписался?

```
function Animal() {}

function Rabbit() {}
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var rabbit = new Rabbit();

alert( rabbit instanceof Rabbit ); выдаст true

Rabbit.prototype = {};


alert( rabbit instanceof Rabbit ); выдаст false!
```

Comment: проверяется один и тот же _rabbit_?

Comment: Да, проверяется один и тот же rabbit

Comment: а почему вы ожидаете чтобы в первом случае конструктор перезаписался ??

Comment: После объявления new Rabbit сделайте проверку

alert( rabbit.constructor === Rabbit ); 
Конструктор перезапишется, но дело в другом.
Что instanceof не совсем на конструктор проверяется, Grundy написал алгоритм проверки его, я просто не совсем понимал как работает instanceof, но то что конструктор в обоих случаях перезаписывается - факт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполнении оператора *instanceof* идет [последовательная проверка прототипов](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance)

И так как перед второй проверкой прототип в `Rabbit` изменился, следующая проверка возвращает `false`.

Фактически вызов этого оператора можно описать следующим циклом:

```
function instanceOf(object, Proto)
    var proto = Proto.prototype;
    while(true){
        var objectProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
        if(objectProto == null) return false;
        if(Object.is(objectProto, proto)) return true;
    }
}
```

Таким образом видно, что после смены прототипа у Rabbit, этот цикл продолжается пока полученный прототип не будет *null* и оператор не вернет *false*.